# Loop through static cells in a single section. UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I have a static UITableView, with a number of sections. One of which contains a lot of cells which will be options (click to checkmark).

I have an NSMutableArray (self.checkedData) that contains the row ID's of the selected rows. I can't figure out how to loop through the cells in a particular section. It's to check whether the row is in the array, if so add a checkmark. So when the view is loaded, the options can be pulled from coredata and then the selected rows marked.

I currently have this for handling the adding of checkmarks. This works fine.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // determine the selected data from the IndexPath.row

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // determine the data from the IndexPath.row

    if ( ![self.checkedData containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]] )
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.checkedData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self.checkedData removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    }    

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an array of all cells in a specific section like this:

```
NSUInteger section = 0;
NSInteger numberOfRowsInSection = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];

NSMutableArray *cellsInSection = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfRowsInSection];

for (NSInteger row = 0; row < numberOfRowsInSection; row++)
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cellsInSection addObject:cell];
}
```

`cellsInSection` array now contains all the cells in the section 0

Comment: Thank's. I wasn't quite sure how to go about it, but this made sense.

Comment: cell can be null here on ios7 if it is invisible at the moment.

Comment: Yes it can. If you really need to access configured instances of cells, you can do it using calling `[tableViewDataSource tableView:tableView cellForRow...]` method instead of [`tableView cellForRow...]` on table view's data source which should always give you non-nil cell for a price of (maybe useless) initializing/dequeuing/configuring cells

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this in viewDidLoad ?:

```
for(NSIndexPath *thisIndexPath in [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]) {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  if ( ![self.checkedData containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]] ) {
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
      [self.checkedData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    } else {
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
      [self.checkedData removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    }
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Appreciate you're help. Felt the other one was more suited to what I wanted, but I understood your answer too. Thanks.